# Excel VBA search for text string in text file dependent on number of columns in excel file

Tags: excel, vba

OK, I have a code to search for a text string in a certain text file.

The file looks like this:
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtEwJ.jpg)
The file name to search in is mentioned in cell B3.
The first text string to search for is in C1 and the result should be the length of the text in C2 starting from the end of the found match with C1 in the text file.
The second text string to search for is in D1 and works the same.

I've got this working with the following code:

```
Sub search2()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String

myFile = "C:\FileLocation\" & [B3]

Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop

Close #1

pos1 = InStr(text, Cells(1, 3).Value)
pos2 = InStr(text, Cells(1, 4).Value)

[C3].Value = Mid(text, pos1 + Len([C1].Value), Len([C2].Value))
[D3].Value = Mid(text, pos2 + Len([D1].Value), Len([D2].Value))

End Sub
```

That works fine, but only works for data in row 3 specifically and if there's 2 columns with search strings.
I wanted it to be more dynamical: I want it to search for the last row with data in column B and from that point search for the Search text1 with Result text1 for to add the Search result1 in C3. and repeat this until the last column containing search text and result text.

I thought this would do the above mentioned, but it doesn't write away any data in any cell:

```
Sub search()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, n As Long, lVal As Long, lCol As Long

On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

lVal = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

myFile = "C:\FileLocation\" & Range("L" & lVal)

Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop

Close #1

For n = 3 To lCol

pos1 = InStr(text, Cells(1, n).Value)
Cells(lVal, n).Value = Mid(text, pos1 + Len(Cells(1, n).Value), Len(Cells(2, n).Value))

Next

End Sub
```

I don't understand why it's not doing what I expect it to.
Is this because I use MID in combination with Cells instead of range?

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I mistyped the letter for the Column to  search for the last value here:

```
myFile = "C:\FileLocation\" & Range("L" & lVal)
```

Changing `L` into `B` solved it all.

I overlooked it a couple of times, but this solves it.